# When/Where to execute a JS function in HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html

What I have is probably simple.

Here's my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MC</title>
        <link href="public/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body data-page="home">
        <div class="avatar" data-type="mc_face"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">mc_face("Voobus");</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" href="public/js/mc_face.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

You see, I have my external javascript file being declared at the very bottom. Right above it, I am trying to execute the function that is in that file (while passing a variable to it). Everything works fine if it's all in the same file, but the goal is to later have that function being executed in a php loop, so I need the seperate.

Am I just going about it all wrong? Why doesn't it work as-is?

This is the error I'm currently getting:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: mc_face is not defined
```

So clearly, it's having a hard time even finding the function in the external file. I've tried it with their orders reversed, with the external file in the header, and some other things. I'm really scratching my head here.

Comment: You've got to put your inline script *after* the import of your script file.  They're evaluated in the order in which they appear.

Comment: I've done that, and just tried again. Same error.

Comment: Any other errors? What's in that file anyway? Are you 100% sure that it's being successfully imported?

Comment: Script `href`? It should be `src` not `href` :)

Comment: Good catch @null !!  There's your answer OP.

Comment: Wow... I'm clearly off my game today. That was really stupid, thanks! Just a brain-fart, I guess. It works after fixing with src.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use src not href. Also put your code below your import.